# How to add active record database back into a Rails 5 created with --skip-active-record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

The rails app in question was initially created using `--skip-active-record` since there was no database needed.

Now there is a need to add in a MySQL database to the app. How can one convert the non-database Rails app to have a database?

Comment: Are you using git on your project?

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo Yes... but the app never had a DB before (it was initially created with the `--skip-active-record` flag)

Answer (score 0):

This is what a I did:

1. Go one level up of your folder app and run the rails new command again, hit enter every time to override the conflicts

> rails new my_app_name -d mysql

2. Use the git tool to see changes in your app files (RubyMine, gitg, smartgit)

Files changed:

```
config/application.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/production.rb
config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
Gemfile
bin/setup
bin/update
test/test_helper.rb
```

New files

```
config/database.yml
app/models/application_record.rb
db/seeds.rb
```

Details(diff view - for removed + added):

config/application.rb

```
-# Pick the frameworks you want:
-require "active_model/railtie"
-require "active_job/railtie"
-# require "active_record/railtie"
-require "action_controller/railtie"
-require "action_mailer/railtie"
-require "action_view/railtie"
-require "action_cable/engine"
-require "sprockets/railtie"
-require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
+require 'rails/all'
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
+# Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
+config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
```

config/environments/production.rb

+# Do not dump schema after migrations.
+config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

Gemfile

```
+# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
+gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.6.0'
```

bin/setup

```
+# puts "\n== Copying sample files =="
+# unless File.exist?('config/database.yml')
+#   cp 'config/database.yml.sample', 'config/database.yml'
+# end

+puts "\n== Preparing database =="
+system! 'bin/rails db:setup'
```

bin/update

```
+puts "\n== Updating database =="
+system! 'bin/rails db:migrate'
```

app/models/application_record.rb

```
+class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
+  self.abstract_class = true
+end
```

config/database.yml

```
+default: &default
+  adapter: mysql2
+  encoding: utf8
+  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
+  username: root
+  password:
+  host: localhost

+development:
+  <<: *default
+  database: app-without-activerecord_development

+test:
+  <<: *default
+  database: app-without-activerecord_test

+production:
+  <<: *default
+  database: app-without-activerecord_production
+  username: app-without-activerecord
+  password: <%= ENV['APP-WITHOUT-ACTIVERECORD_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that I did after reading your question was to create 2 new projects on my computer

`rails new test-db` and `rails new test-no-db --skip-active-record` now I should have 2 projects that are identical but 1 does not have active-record
now can can run a difference between the 2 directories `diff --brief -r test-db/ test-no-db/`

files that change

1) Gemfile

```
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
```

2) app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require activestorage
```

3) Add this file

```
#test-db/app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

4) test-db/bin/setup

```
chdir APP_ROOT do
  ...
  puts "\n== Preparing database =="
  system! 'bin/rails db:setup'
  ...
end
```

you can go threw the rest of the files to see what is different. 
I know that this is not the solution that you wanted but its what I would have done